# How does an electrode (e.g., an ECG lead) measure biopotential changes?

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics

In many medical procedures, electrodes are used to measure various physiologic biopotentials. The most common example is that of an ECG procedure, in which electrodes attempt to sense changes in voltage associated with cardiac cell depolarization and repolarization. Other examples can be found in invasive monitoring of the brain.

However, I'm not exactly clear how an electrode actually, at a physics levels, converts the movement of K+/Ca2+/Na+ ions (depending on the cell) into a voltage # that you might see on a computer screen. That is, how does the electrode transduce the changes in ion movement in a cell to a voltage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How does the electrode transduce the changes in ion movement in a cell to a voltage?

The electrode is either touching the skin tissue or is very close to it. When potential of an element of tissue near the electrode changes, this means there are changes in macroscopic electric charge distribution in the tissue (the reason has to do with biology, there is motion and buildup of electric charge, due to ions and membranes). This change then causes change of electric charge distribution (via electrostatic forces) in the electrodes. The measuring device (some kind of oscilloscope) can measure difference of potential between two electrodes or between one electrode and local ground.